# Moving over thumbnail gallery by one column in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<style>
/* Navigation */         
#logo{width: 248px;
      padding-bottom:25px;
      padding-top:25px;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a { 

  margin-right:-75px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  text-transform:uppercase;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    background: black;
    color:white;    
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    height: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    max-height: none;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    width: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
    background:white;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-x: visible;
  }

.navbar
{
    max-width:250px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-radius:0;
    border:0;
}   

.navbar-nav,
.navbar-nav > li,
.navbar-left,
.navbar-right,
.navbar-header
{float:none !important;}

.navbar-right .dropdown-menu {left:0;right:auto;}
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}


.sidebar-nav{background: white}

}

</style> 



<div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="sidebar-nav">
                <div class="navbar navbar-default avbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      </button>
                      <span class="visible-xs navbar-brand">Sidebar menu</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <img id="logo" src="assets/img/logo.jpg"/> 
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-1"><a href="#">Animation</a></li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-2"><a href="#">Commercial</a></li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-3"><a href="#">Documentary</a></li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-4"><a href="#">Film</a></li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-5"><a href="#">Music</a></li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-6"><a href="#">Video Games</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>

                      </ul>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    <div id="portfolio">
        <div class="pContainer">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>


    </div>






      </div>
```

I need to move over the thumbnail gallery by one column. I tried many different ways but everything messes up the layout of the thumbnail gallery itself. I posted this code here but I think it is easier to visit the website to see what I am talking about http://velnikolic.com/video/portfolio.html

[image]

Comment: .col-xs-offset-* should do the trick.

Comment: does not work because the navigation is on the side and the portfolio section is made up of several tiny columns that work as a unit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not so much on moving your gallery a column over, but a better bootstrap html architecture. You declared your sidebar to occupy col-sm-3 but not the gallery to occupy the rest of it (col-sm-9). Do that and then, again, re-distribute your columns inside to show in the layout you want (3 or 4 columns) it doesn't matter.

I made this [**demo**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/JbyrrG) for you with your code

Here is what I suggest you do. It will center all your elements to use most of your browser real estate and will proportionally fix your gutters so that nothing is too heavy to one side or the other.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="sidebar-nav">
            <div class="navbar navbar-default avbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                    <span class="visible-xs navbar-brand">Sidebar menu</span>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <img id="logo" src="assets/img/logo.jpg" />
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-1"><a href="#">Animation</a></li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-2"><a href="#">Commercial</a></li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-3"><a href="#">Documentary</a></li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-4"><a href="#">Film</a></li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-5"><a href="#">Music</a></li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-6"><a href="#">Video Games</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div id="portfolio">
        <div class="pContainer">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
    </div>

    <video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="polina.jpg" id="bgvid">
    <!--<source src="polina.webm" type="video/webm">-->
    <source src="assets/videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>


    <footer class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="footer-container container-fluid">
            <div class="social-links">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest fa-lg"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

</div>
```

**EDIT**

to add more gutter to the gallery, modify the thumbnail bootstrap class as follows. Also hiding the overflow to your sidenav container will stop it from leaking into the next col-sm-*.

```
.thumbnail {
    max-width: 231px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.sidebar-nav {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying about html architecture but this essentially gives the same aesthetic results. The design looks cluttered without extra space between the nav and the thumbnails and offsetting by one column ruins the layout of the gallery.

Comment: All you have to do is fix the width and margin. I updated the codepen. Oh and fix your nav so that it dooesn't leak

Comment: The nav leak was a design choice by the client. I added a picture so you see what I mean. Essentially the green area should be 8 columns total and offset by 1. I know the design looks like its just 9 columns total, but the client asked me if I could add more space between the two sections (about 1 column's worth) I hope the picture makes it more clear?

Comment: Ah instead of offsetting I just had to "col-sm-push-1" and it didn't mess anything up. Thank you for your efforts Lotus. If you think theres a better way of utilizing bootstrap rather then pushing, I'm open to it hearing it, but I think push was what i was looking for.

Comment: That was always in the back of my head, but I don't like to offer it too much becasue 9 times out of 10 most people don't need it and it ends up being a simple architecture thing. Now that you've decided to go that route, reset the push on bigger layouts, that push is only for the specified col-sm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129129/discussion-between-velibor-nikolic-and-lotusms).